# How to use django-filter package for foreign key fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-filter

**Hi all!**

*New in Django, and confused, help is appreciated! I've created a table, , thanks to a stackoverflow users, like:*

| Organization | Total amount of appeals | Amount of written form appeals | Amount of oral form appeals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Organization 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| Organization 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Have three models:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class AppealForm(models.Model):
    form_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Appeal(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    appeal_form = models.ForeignKey(AppealForm, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applicant_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    appeal_date = models.DateField()
```

Objects of **Organization** model:

| organization_name |
| --- |
| Organization 1 |
| Organization 2 |

Objects of **AppealForm** model:

| form_name |
| --- |
| In written form |
| In oral form |

Objects of **Appeal** model:

| organization | appeal_form | applicant_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Organization 1 | In written form | First and Last name |
| Organization 1 | In oral form | First and Last name |
| Organization 1 | In oral form | First and Last name |
| Organization 2 | In written form | First and Last name |
| Organization 2 | In oral form | First and Last name |

In the function of **views.py** file, I've created a query to render, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

organizations = Organization.objects.annotate(
).annotate(
    total=Count('appeal'),
    total_written=Count('appeal', filter=Q(appeal__appeal_form__form_name='in written form')),
    total_oral=Count('appeal', filter=Q('appeal__appeal_form__form_name='in oral form'))
)
```

And now I want to filter table contents by **AppealForm** model and date of appeals (**appeal_date** field of **Appeal model**). Case: User opens a table and from search bar above the table chooses which appeal form and/or the range of dates to see.

Question: How to filter the query which is above in views.py using django-filter package?

Comment: Which model are you filtering? Organisation or Appeal?

Comment: Hi @nigel222, I'm filtering Organization model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general way to define a complicated filter is to use the method argument. I can't say I completely understand your problem, but you can apply any filter for which you can  dream up a queryset in this way.  In outline:

```
import django-filters as DF

class SomeFilters( DF.FilterSet):

    name = DF.xxxFilter( method='my_method', field_name='object_field', label='whatever',  ...)
    ...

    def my_method( self, qs, name, value):
        # in here you create a new more restrictive queryset based on qs
        # to implement your filter, and return it.
        # name is the field name. Note, you don't have to use or follow it
        # value is the value that the user typed

        qs = qs.filter( ...) # or .exclude, or complicated stuff  
        return qs
```

Here's a fairly simple method that I wrote to create an annotation with the value of a field stripped of spaces, and then to do a text-contains filter on that.

```
    def filter_array_desc( self, qs, name, value):
        value = value.replace(' ','')
        qs = qs.annotate(
            arr_d_nospaces = Replace( 'array_desc', Value(' '), Value('')) # delete all spaces
        ).filter(
            arr_d_nospaces__icontains = value )
        return qs
```

Here's a general one that can be applied to any field through a `ChoiceFilter` to filter whether the field is blank or not:

```
    YESNO = (('Y','Yes'), ('N','No'))
    marr_b = FD.ChoiceFilter( field_name='marr', label='M_array is blank',  method='filter_blank_yesno', 
                              choices=YESNO, empty_label="Don't Care" )
    ...

    def filter_blank_yesno( self, qs, name, value):
        if value=="Y":
            return qs.filter(**{ name:'' })
        elif value=="N":
            return qs.exclude( **{ name:'' })
        raise ValueError(f'filter_blank_yesno received value="{value}" which is neither "Y" nor "N"')
```

Hope this helps. You will basically be filtering by following relationships between your models, using double-underscores to move between models, and possibly annotating and filtering on the anotation, or doing things with Q objects and suchlike.